# Windows balloon notification works on Windows 10 but not Windows 11

Tags: c#, windows, notifications

I have shamelessly copied the following coded and modifications of it from other postings on Stackoverflow and it works fine on a VM running Windows 10; the two icons display fine as do the title and the tip text.

Unfortunately when I run it on my host machine which is running Windows 11 nothing displays. Where am I going wrong?

```
   public static void showBalloon(string title, string body)
        {
            NotifyIcon notifyIcon = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon();
            notifyIcon.Visible = true;
            notifyIcon.Icon =  Properties.Resources.Logo_grey_white_fill;
            notifyIcon.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Info;

            if (title != null)
            {
                notifyIcon.BalloonTipTitle = title;
            }

            if (body != null)
            {
                notifyIcon.BalloonTipText = body;
            }

            notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(30000);
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            notifyIcon.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: [Working fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UO9C1.png) ... check your windows settings as is stated in duplicated question

Comment: also not setting `BalloonTipText` is throwing an exception ... so if you are swallowing exceptions than this can be culprit (but is blind guess)

Comment: Hi Slevin I didn't understand your advice about checking windows settings, could you please expand as the link you have provided is to a screenshot that doesn't appear to relate to any Windows settings

Comment: I have stepped through it in debug in Windows 11 and no exceptions are thrown

Comment: I don't remeber what settings ... but I'm pretty sure that similar question was already asked and there was mentioned about some windows notification settings ... feel free to search it

Comment: Bingo, I checked the Windows notifications settings in my Windows installation which is under System | Notifications and mine was turned off!  All working now thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that my Windows 11 machine that had the Windows Notifications turned off. Once switched on, the notifications showed as expected